# C++ Bit Shift With Same Constant in Opposite Directions, Different Result With Minor Code Changes

Tags: c++, templates, bit-manipulation, compiler-optimization, bit-shift

I have a template function

```
template< uint8_t HOW_FAR_CONSTANT, uint8_t START_CONSTANT, uint8_t ORIGINAL_CONSTANT>
uint8_t Foo();
```

In `Foo` I do something like this

```
const uint8_t OFFSET_CONSTANT = ( START_CONSTANT + HOW_FAR_CONSTANT );
const uint8_t RESULT_CONSTANT = ( ( ORIGINAL_CONSTANT << OFFSET_CONSTANT ) >> OFFSET_CONSTANT );
```

And it does not truncate the bits, it results in:

```
ORIGINAL: 10101010
RESULT: 10101010
```

However, if I make a slight modification

```
const uint8_t OFFSET_CONSTANT = ( START_CONSTANT + HOW_FAR_CONSTANT );
const uint8_t RESULT_0_CONSTANT = ( ORIGINAL_CONSTANT << OFFSET_CONSTANT );
const uint8_t RESULT_CONSTANT = ( RESULT_0_CONSTANT >> OFFSET_CONSTANT );
```

I get

```
ORIGINAL: 10101010
RESULT 0 (lets say OFFSET_CONSTANT is 2): 10101000
RESULT: 00101010
```

I am wondering if this is a bad compiler optimization. Can anyone explain this?

UPDATE:

Tried this on compiler explorer, its definitely standard behavior and not a bad compiler optimization.

Comment: `const uint8_t RESULT_CONSTANT = ( RESULT_0_CONSTANT << OFFSET_CONSTANT );`. Shouldn't this be `const uint8_t RESULT_CONSTANT = ( RESULT_0_CONSTANT >> OFFSET_CONSTANT );` for the 2 codes to be identical.

Comment: @aep Yep! My bad, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is neither optimization. There is a truncation due to storing a result of a shift operation in an object of the type `uint8_t`.

```
const uint8_t RESULT_0_CONSTANT = ( ORIGINAL_CONSTANT << OFFSET_CONSTANT );
```

When the shift operation is performed the integral promotions are applied to operands.

So in this expression

```
const uint8_t RESULT_CONSTANT = ( ( ORIGINAL_CONSTANT << OFFSET_CONSTANT ) >> OFFSET_CONSTANT );
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the sub-expression `( ORIGINAL_CONSTANT << OFFSET_CONSTANT )` has the type `int` instead of `uint8_t`.

From the C++ Standard (5.8 Shift operators)

> 1. 1 The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right. The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type **and integral promotions are performed**.

Comment: To tack on, we now have `std::byte`, which has closed bitwise operations.